# Web page with JavaScript program's label is not aligning with the other labels/text areas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I apologize for asking silly questions, but I have tried to mess with the CSS and changed very little. I am trying to get the label/dropdown (which says "withdrawal" by default to align with the others and also get rid of some of the space between the text areas so that it looks more like the screenshot provided by my instructor. I did manage to reduce some of the extra space between areas by reducing the pixels, but I am not certain how to get it to look exactly like the screenshot.

If anyone would please give suggestions, I would genuinely appreciate it.

```js
var pad_left = function(text, width, pad) {  //sets up text area formatting
 var result = text.toString();
 while (result.length < width) {
  result = pad + result;
 }
 return result;  // populates text area
}

var pad_right = function(text, width, pad) { // sets up text area formatting
 var result = text.toString();
 while (result.length < width) {
  result = result + pad;
 }
 return result;  
}

var getResults = function(results) { // actual calculation functions 
 if (results.length == 0) {
  return "";
 }

 var balance = 2000;  / /actual format of text area
 var list = pad_right("Date", 12, " ");
 list += pad_right("Amount", 12, " ");
 list += pad_right("Running Balance", 15, " ") + "\n";
 list += pad_right("", 11, "-") + " ";
 list += pad_right("", 11, "-") + " ";
 list += pad_right("", 15, "-") + "\n";
 
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {  // loop to calculate balances
   var trans = results[i];
  list += pad_right(trans["date"], 12, " ");
  if(trans["type"] == "withdrawal") // withdrawal calculation
  {
   balance -= trans["amount"]
   list += "$" + pad_left( "-" + trans["amount"].toFixed(2), 11, " ") + " ";
  } else { //for Deposits
   balance += trans["amount"]
   list += "$" + pad_left( trans["amount"].toFixed(2), 11, " ") + " ";
  }
    
  list += "$" + pad_left(balance.toFixed(2), 14, " ") + "\n";  
 }
 return list;
}
var get_runningBalance = function(results) {  // function to calculate Running Balance
 var runningBalance = 0, amount;
 for (var i in results) {
  runningBalance =  startBal - "amount" ;
  runningBalance += parseInt(runningBalance.toFixed(2));
 }
 return runningBalance;
}

var get_startBal = function(transactions){ // fills Starting Balance
 return 2000;
}

var get_totalDep = function(transactions){  // function to calculate Total Deposits
 var totalDep = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
  var trans = transactions[i];
  if(trans["type"] == "deposit")
  {
   totalDep += trans["amount"]
  }
 }
 return totalDep;
}

var get_totalWd = function(transactions){ // function to calculate Total Withdrawals
 var totalWd = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
  var trans = transactions[i];
  if(trans["type"] == "withdrawal")
  {
   totalWd -= trans["amount"]
  }
 }
 return totalWd;
}

var get_endBal = function(transactions){ // function to calculate Ending Balance
 var balance = 2000;
 for(var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
  var trans = transactions[i];
  if(trans["type"] == "withdrawal")
  {
   balance -= trans["amount"]
  } else { // Is Deposit
   balance += trans["amount"]
  }
 }
 return balance.toFixed(2);
}​

// sets up the global variables and arrays for the functions
var balances = [];
var transactions = [];

var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
// pulls the info from text boxes
var update_display = function() {
 $("startBal").value = get_startBal(transactions);
 $("totalDep").value = get_totalDep(transactions);
 $("totalWd").value = get_totalWd(transactions);
 $("endBal").value = get_endBal(transactions);
 
 $("date").value = "";
 $("amount").value = "";
 
 $("date").focus();
 
 $("results").value = getResults(transactions);
}
// function to add transactions to the text area 
var addTrans_click = function () {
 var trans = [];
 trans["date"] = $("date").value;
 trans["amount"] = parseFloat($("amount").value);
 trans["type"] = $("type").value;
 
 if (trans["date"] == "") return;
 if (isNaN(trans["amount"])) return;
  
 transactions.push(trans);
 update_display(); 
}
// the event handlers 
window.onload = function () {
 $("addTrans").onclick = addTrans_click;
 $("date").focus();
}​
```

```css
body {
    background: none repeat scroll;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#content {
    background: none repeat scroll;
    border: 8px solid gray;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
}
h1, h2 {
    text-align: left;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    width: 10em;
}
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
select {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10em;
}
.formLayout label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 10em;
}
.formLayout input {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.formLayout br {
    clear: both;
}
​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Monthly Balance Calculator</title>    
    <link href="monthly_balance.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="mbc_library.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="monthly_balance.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="content">
  <h1>Monthly Balance Calculator</h1>
  <br />
  <h2>Add Transaction</h2>
  <hr />
  <br />
  
  <div class="formLayout">
   <label for="date">Date:</label>
   <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
   <br />
   <br />
   
   <label for="type">Type:</label>
   <select name="type" id="type">
     <option value="withdrawal">Withdrawal</option>
     <option value="deposit">Deposit</option>
   </select>
   <br />
     
   <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
   <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"/>
   <br />
   <br />
   
   <label>&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="button" id="addTrans" value="Add Transaction" />
   <br />
  </div>
 
  <h2>Transactions</h2>
  <hr />
  <br />
  
  <textarea name="results" id="results" rows="10" cols="60" disabled="disabled">
  </textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
 
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <hr />
  <br />
  
  <div class="formLayout">
   <label for="startBal">Starting Balance:</label>
   <input type="text" name="startBal" id="startBal"
    class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   <br />
   
   <label for="totalDep">Total Deposits:</label>
   <input type="text" name="totalDep" id="totalDep"
    class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   <br />
   
   <label for="totalWd">Total Withdrawals:</label>
   <input type="text" name="totalWd" id="totalWd"
       class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   <br />
   
   <label for="endBal">Ending Balance</label>
   <input type="text" name="endBal" id="endBal"
    class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
</body>
   
</html>
   
​
```

Note, I had to add BOTH JS files in the same form because this site only allows me to paste two, despite the fact that I added two to the HTML page[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need. 
Check with below code.

```js
var pad_left = function(text, width, pad) {  //sets up text area formatting
 var result = text.toString();
 while (result.length < width) {
  result = pad + result;
 }
 return result;  // populates text area
}

var pad_right = function(text, width, pad) { // sets up text area formatting
 var result = text.toString();
 while (result.length < width) {
  result = result + pad;
 }
 return result;  
}

var getResults = function(results) { // actual calculation functions 
 if (results.length == 0) {
  return "";
 }

 var balance = 2000;  / /actual format of text area
 var list = pad_right("Date", 12, " ");
 list += pad_right("Amount", 12, " ");
 list += pad_right("Running Balance", 15, " ") + "\n";
 list += pad_right("", 11, "-") + " ";
 list += pad_right("", 11, "-") + " ";
 list += pad_right("", 15, "-") + "\n";
 
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {  // loop to calculate balances
   var trans = results[i];
  list += pad_right(trans["date"], 12, " ");
  if(trans["type"] == "withdrawal") // withdrawal calculation
  {
   balance -= trans["amount"]
   list += "$" + pad_left( "-" + trans["amount"].toFixed(2), 11, " ") + " ";
  } else { //for Deposits
   balance += trans["amount"]
   list += "$" + pad_left( trans["amount"].toFixed(2), 11, " ") + " ";
  }
    
  list += "$" + pad_left(balance.toFixed(2), 14, " ") + "\n";  
 }
 return list;
}
var get_runningBalance = function(results) {  // function to calculate Running Balance
 var runningBalance = 0, amount;
 for (var i in results) {
  runningBalance =  startBal - "amount" ;
  runningBalance += parseInt(runningBalance.toFixed(2));
 }
 return runningBalance;
}

var get_startBal = function(transactions){ // fills Starting Balance
 return 2000;
}

var get_totalDep = function(transactions){  // function to calculate Total Deposits
 var totalDep = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
  var trans = transactions[i];
  if(trans["type"] == "deposit")
  {
   totalDep += trans["amount"]
  }
 }
 return totalDep;
}

var get_totalWd = function(transactions){ // function to calculate Total Withdrawals
 var totalWd = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
  var trans = transactions[i];
  if(trans["type"] == "withdrawal")
  {
   totalWd -= trans["amount"]
  }
 }
 return totalWd;
}

var get_endBal = function(transactions){ // function to calculate Ending Balance
 var balance = 2000;
 for(var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++){
  var trans = transactions[i];
  if(trans["type"] == "withdrawal")
  {
   balance -= trans["amount"]
  } else { // Is Deposit
   balance += trans["amount"]
  }
 }
 return balance.toFixed(2);
}​

// sets up the global variables and arrays for the functions
var balances = [];
var transactions = [];

var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
// pulls the info from text boxes
var update_display = function() {
 $("startBal").value = get_startBal(transactions);
 $("totalDep").value = get_totalDep(transactions);
 $("totalWd").value = get_totalWd(transactions);
 $("endBal").value = get_endBal(transactions);
 
 $("date").value = "";
 $("amount").value = "";
 
 $("date").focus();
 
 $("results").value = getResults(transactions);
}
// function to add transactions to the text area 
var addTrans_click = function () {
 var trans = [];
 trans["date"] = $("date").value;
 trans["amount"] = parseFloat($("amount").value);
 trans["type"] = $("type").value;
 
 if (trans["date"] == "") return;
 if (isNaN(trans["amount"])) return;
  
 transactions.push(trans);
 update_display(); 
}
// the event handlers 
window.onload = function () {
 $("addTrans").onclick = addTrans_click;
 $("date").focus();
}​
```

```css
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 8px solid gray;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
}
h1, h2 {
    text-align: left;
}
h2 {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 10em;
}
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
select {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.formLayout label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 10em;
}
.formLayout input {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.formLayout br {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Monthly Balance Calculator</title>    
    <link href="monthly_balance.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="mbc_library.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="monthly_balance.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="content">
  <h1>Monthly Balance Calculator</h1>
  <br />
  <h2>Add Transaction</h2>
  <hr />
  <br />
  
  <div class="formLayout">
   <label for="date">Date:</label>
   <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
   <br />
   
   <label for="type">Type:</label>
   <select name="type" id="type">
     <option value="withdrawal">Withdrawal</option>
     <option value="deposit">Deposit</option>
   </select>
   <br />
     
   <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
   <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"/>
   <br />
   
   <label>&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="button" id="addTrans" value="Add Transaction" />
   <br />
  </div>
 
  <h2>Transactions</h2>
  <hr />
  <br />
  
  <textarea name="results" id="results" rows="10" cols="60" disabled="disabled">
  </textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
 
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <hr />
  <br />
  
  <div class="formLayout">
   <label for="startBal">Starting Balance:</label>
   <input type="text" name="startBal" id="startBal"
    class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   
   <label for="totalDep">Total Deposits:</label>
   <input type="text" name="totalDep" id="totalDep"
    class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   
   <label for="totalWd">Total Withdrawals:</label>
   <input type="text" name="totalWd" id="totalWd"
       class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
   
   <label for="endBal">Ending Balance</label>
   <input type="text" name="endBal" id="endBal"
    class="disabled" disabled="disabled"/>
   <br />
  </div>
</body>
   
</html>
   
​
```

Comment: Strange, it was calculating a while ago, before I asked the question? Let me see....